# XSLT Undeclared entity. Now giving Compile Error, but it used to work

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

**Short Summary**

Our XSLT stylesheet is failing to compile when the !ENTITY declarations are actually used.  Saying 'Reference to undeclared entity'.

I can leave the declaration in place, and comment out the actual call to that declaration, and everything works fine.

What's weird is this same process worked fine for the last 10 years... and was used as recently as 2 months ago, without any known modifications.

Trying to debug legacy code, that hasn't been modified for a decade, and I have zero understanding of XSLT's....

---

**All the juicy details**

The **transform.Load** function call (XslCompiledTransform.Load) *figure 1 below*, is failing.

```
Dim transfom As New XslCompiledTransform()

Dim readerSettings As New XmlReaderSettings()

readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore

Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(styleSheetFilePath, readerSettings)
    transfom.Load(reader, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, resolver)
End Using
```

The error message its giving is

```
XSLT compile error.

Reference to undeclared entity 'cr'. Line 10, position 4.

StackTrace Information
*********************************************
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader, Boolean include)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.Load(Compiler compiler, Object stylesheet, XmlResolver xmlResolver)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.Compiler.Compile(Object stylesheet, XmlResolver xmlResolver, QilExpression& qil)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal(Object stylesheet, XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(XmlReader stylesheet, XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)
```

And when I look at the XSLT file being loaded, Line 10... it's the **&cr;**  entity reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY cr "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        &cr;
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
            <xsl:call-template name="RemoveEmpty" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
..[redacted]..
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the DtdProcessing property to `readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse`?

Comment: From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#dtd): *"XML 1.0 DTDs do not support XML Namespaces and thus cannot correctly describe the allowed structure of an XSLT stylesheet."*

Comment: @Alejandro Did the spec recently change?  I'm not sure why it would have worked for a decade, until just recently..?

Comment: @TimC That works!!!!  I have no idea what changed (maybe something in the .NET framework DLL for System.XML?) .... but thank you!

Comment: @adam That quote explain why your stylesheet fails when you use a validating parser that also process your DTD: if you use a QName with namespace prefix as root element you will need to have the same QName with the same prefix in the DOCTYPE declaration **because XML 1.0 DTDs do not support XML Namespaces**. If you chose to use a non validating parser you might not get your entity resolved...

Answer (score 0):

After `!ENTITY` there should be the entity name (in your case `cr`)
and then the character code.

As I understand, there should be the code of *Carriage Return* char,
i.e. 13 (decimal).

So the fragment in question should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY cr "&#13;">
]>
```

In my opinion, `"<xsl:text> </xsl:text>"` is something unusual,
because in other places in XSLT code it means a **space**.